# Cheapest reverb to stick in analog audio circuitry?

Tags: audio, analog

What are the cheapest (<$5 in large quantities) reverb implementations you can think of for interfacing with analog audio circuitry?  It can be crappy but, of course, better is better.

Answer (score 6):

Another option is a Microchip [Microstick](http://www.microchip.com/stellent/idcplg?IdcService=SS_GET_PAGE&nodeId=1406&dDocName=en548414). It comes with a 40 MIPS dsPIC chip that is suitable for implementing a reverb algorithm. Audio could be sampled with the on-chip ADC and output using PWM; very few external parts would be needed. The dsPIC chip on its own is about $5, it's a lot less in large quantities.

Comment: Is PWM output (with some additional filtering) a good way to dump audio?  I'd think the "right" way would be to kick it out via I²S or similar to a purpose built DAC (though I don't know what they cost)

Comment: He isn't all that concerned with quality. PWM should be fine, and will keep the cost down to his required $5.

Answer (score 2):

There's always the option of a plate or spring reverb - it's not pretty but it's certainly low cost.

It can be built for cheap using a couple of piezoelectric transducers and a lump of material with a nice resonance.

You can drive the signal into a small metal plate with one of the piezo disks, the other is used as a contact microphone - it picks up the signal after it's been transmitted through the metal. (I've done it with my wooden workbench before, it sounds quite good)

It's the same sort of thing that's used in the back of old-school guitar amps, like this spring reverb - http://www.amplifiedparts.com/products/amp_parts/P-R4AB3C1B

You can beef them up easily too -

http://www.sageelectronics.com/bovasound/emt.html

That EMT one may have cost a few bucks!, but if your just making a small one with a couple of piezo disks, you should be able to make one for less than 10 US$

However, despite the limitations you can get some really fantastic results with a plate or spring style reverb.

:)

Comment: Hmmm....  Is there a substance through which acoustic waves travel very slowly (without being absorbed)?  Then you could make a miniature room out of it and use transducers to simulate the reverb of a much larger room.  When I first heard of plate reverbs I thought this is what they're doing, but sound travels more quickly through metal, not more slowly.

Comment: @endolith: that's where the springs come in; the effective length of a 30cm spring is several meters.

Answer (score 1):

What about the [FV-1 from Spin Semiconductor](http://www.profusionplc.com/pro/gex/pcatdtl0?ipartno=SPN1001-FV1)?

According to [this page](http://www.profusionplc.com/pro/gex/pcatdtl0?ipartno=SPN1001-FV1), they can be had for about $12, in individual quantities.

Here is a [spec sheet.](http://www.spinsemi.com/Products/datasheets/spn1001/FV-1.pdf)

See also http://www.echotapper.nl/dev/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=41&Itemid=45